# How to nest sql results with joins

Tags: php, sql, join

I have to DB Tables

```
Macro Table:
ID | title | description

Micro Table:
ID | title | description | macro_id
```

macro_id in the "Micro Table" matches an ID of the "Macro Table". I have many Micros to one Maco.

I'm trying to write a sql statement that would give me some result like this in PHP.

```
[
  {
    ID : 3, title : "some title", description : "some desc", micros : [ 
     {
       ID : some number,
       title : "some title",
       description : "some description", 
       macro_id : 3
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

An array of objects , where each object is from the macro table, and then within each macro object an array of "micro" objects that go with that particular Macro based on the matching ID's of "macro_id" in the micro table and "ID" in the macro table

I tried doing various joins

```
 SELECT * FROM macros JOIN micros ON macros.macro_id=micros.micro_id
```

But that is just returning it in one row, instead of nesting it.

EDIT: This is what I'm doing (it's in codeigniter) which gives me the result I'm looking for. It just seems inefficient

```
 $this->load->model('macros_model','',true);
    $this->load->model('micros_model', '', true);
    $all_macros = $this->macros_model->get_all_macros();

    $all_lessons = array();
    foreach($all_macros as $macro){
        $micros = $this->micros_model->get_all_micros_for_macro($macro['macro_id']);
        $macro['micros'] = $micros;
        array_push($all_lessons, $macro);

    }
```

The Sql queries in the get_all_macros and get_all_micros_for_macro is just SELECT * FROM macros, and SELECT * FROM micro WHERE macro_id = $macro_id

Comment: You need to be more clear about the exact output you expect from your query.

Comment: @juergend updated to make it a little more clear

Comment: I meant: Since the SQL query does not return objects but only rows it would be better to add the sql result you expect and not the PHP output after reading and processing the query.

Comment: So maybe i'm asking the wrong question... I guess if I want the result as I outline, I need to do multiple SQL queries? I guess the question is how would I get this result that I'm looking for?

Comment: I guess it can be done with one query. And then be processed in PHP. But I can not speek for the PHP part due to my lack of knowledge about it.

Comment: In php you can echo query results that exist on one row throughout multiple lines, if that is what you are trying to do. I'm not sure why you need to have the sql result essentially be vertical and show the same record on multiple lines, with each line showing certain fields. Normally you would do that after the fact.

Comment: Nesting has to be PHP. I'd be worried about the volume though. Think I'd be looking a tree or other expanding view and then just querying out the micro data by macro_id when it was required myself.

Comment: So basically I would query all the macros, and then all the micros separate and combine them with php?

Comment: I don't see why you need 2 queries. You can use the query you have and then when you echo the results show the fields however you want. Ie. if on a different line use <br> as one method.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Because it just comes back as one sql row... and I can have multiple micros within a macro

Comment: If you have multiple micros within a macro I don't see how it would only come back with one row. Can you post the ddl for your tables and a few example rows?

Comment: Btw the query you gave conflicts with the 2 tables' columns that you listed, it's unclear which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Following example might be helpful (not tested though)..

```
$query = '
            SELECT 
                macroTable.ID as macroID,
                macroTable.Title as macroTitle,
                macroTable.Description as macroDescription,
                microTable.ID as microID,
                microTable.ID as microTitle,
                microTable.ID as microDescription
            FROM  
                macroTable
                INNER JOIN microTable ON macroTable.ID = microTable.macro_id
            ORDER BY
                macroID
        ';

$resultArray = executeQuery($query);

if ($resultArray){

   $nestedResults = array();

   $foreach ($resultArray as $row){

       $macroId = $row['macroID'];
       if (isset($nestedResults)){
           $nestedResults[$macroId]['micros'][] = array(
                                                          'microID'   =>   $row['microID'],
                                                          'microTitle'   =>   $row['microTitle'],
                                                          'microDescription'   =>   $row['microDescription'],
                                                       ); 
       } else {
           $nestedResults[$macroId] = array(
                                               'macroTitle'   =>   $row['macroTitle'],
                                               'macroDescription'   =>   $row['macroDescription'],  
                                               'micros'    =>  array()
                                           );
       }
   }

}
```